# Is there any way to use apps script to add an exception to a sheet protection?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet-protection

I'm making this city thing in google sheets, and I want to be able to add an exception to a sheet protection(see what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iWCs.png)). Is there any way to do this programmatically with apps script?

I tried getting the sheet protection and calling `.setRange` on it, but that didn't work. I also couldn't find anything about this in the apps script documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges)) to set the ranges that can be edited on otherwise protected sheet.